Longest TSP in the unitary disc
I have the unitary disc $D=\{(x,y) \in R^2: x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\} $, and an integer $n \geq 2$. I want to select $n$ points in $D$ to maximise the length shortest path that connects them all. In other words, I am searching for the worst case scenario of the TSP. Is there any known result for this? Thanks!

This question was asked for the unit square before.

Great, thanks! For the circle I found this reference that talks exactly about my question, although a bit old https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/0402010
